# grails - hasErrors()

Tags: grails

My controller has this (testing) code:

```
println domainInstance.hasErrors()
render (view: "edit", model: [domainInstance: domainInstance])
```

the `println` prints `false` to the console, but the gsp renders errors using `<g:hasErrors>`.

Why would this be happeining?

Comment: It seems that the domain instance gets validated somewhere in/after the `render` statement. So `hasErrors()` returns `true` (as expected) if called after `domainInstance.validate()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would help if you showed the GSP code, but my guess is that `hasErrors()` returns true, because you haven't called `validate()`.

The `hasErrors()` method doesn't perform validation, but just reports whether errors were detected the last time validation was performed. So I suspect that some time after the call to `hasErrors()` and before the call to `<g:hasErrors>` validation is being performed.

Anyhow, if you replace the call to

```
println domainInstance.hasErrors()
```

with

```
println domainInstance.validate()
```

that should fix it